# getting __str__ returned non-string (type Operator) in django

Tags: python, django

i try to add data in admin and i am getting error

```
__str__ returned non-string (type Operator)
```

models.py

```
class Operator(models.Model):
person          = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="operators")
tag_id          = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
operator_id     = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
license_grade   = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, choices=LICENSE_CHOICES)
hired_date      = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
men_hour        = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.operator_id
```

can you help solve this problem?

Comment: How about you don't `return self.person`, which **isn't a string**, from `__str__`?! What is unclear about the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cure is quite obvious: make your `__str__` method return a string, not a `Person` instance.

Comment: i try return self.operator_id but its same error. how?

Comment: @GergőLeonidas because `self.operator_id` **also isn't a string?!**

Comment: You defined `operator_id` has allowing NULL and defaulting to NULL. Database's NULL type translates to `None` in Python, and `None` is NOT a string. _You have to make sure `__str__` returns a string, and nothing else than a string_. Period.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a `Foreignfield` type in `__str__` function. It must return a string. You can return one of the `CharField` which specifies the object or simply a string specific to the object.

If you want to return `self.operator_id`, then remove `null=True` from the Field.

Comment: Actually you can return whatever _as long as it's a string_.